# AppleScript Question (Copy email contents, run Automator App)

Tags: applescript, apple-mail

I have a Mail filter that will run an Autoscript that will copy the messages content and then run a Automator App.  However it is not working.  It doesn't launch the Automator App or copy the contents.

So I have an email that comes in, it tells this Applescript to run.  If I go in and edit the Applescript (even 24 hours later with no shut down, only sleep) and remove everything but the last line and click save the AppleScript launches the app. I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the first block of code.  When the email comes in I have Mail set to make a sound, run the script and delete the email, so I know that the script is told to run.

- How can I delete the email file?
- Why    is there an error in which it
  only    runs after I open the
  AppleScript in    the AppleScript
  editor? This is    really dumb.

This is the current Applescript below:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages matchmsgs for rule mailrule
        tell application "Mail"
            set msg to item 1 of matchmsgs
            set msgcontent to (content of msg) as Unicode text
        end tell
        set the clipboard to msgcontent
        tell application "/Users/me/Docs/Update App.app" to activate
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: How and where is this not working?

Comment: I save this in an applescript and have the mail.app program run it when a email that comes in that fits the filter.  Edited question to include some details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe for a mail rule that all of your applescript code must be within the **on perform mail action with messages matchmsgs for rule mailrule** block of code. As such try moving the line **tell application "Update App" to activate** to just after the line **set the clipboard to msgcontent**.

Comment: I also want it to delete the message that invoked the AppleScript, however if I do it in Mail the AppleScript will not be able to copy the message contents how can I delete the mail message in the AppleScript? Thanks!

Comment: Also I have found that it only runs the app after a message has been sent to mail, and after I open up the Script in the AppleScript Editor, I don't know why it won't run it without me opening it up, I don't click run, I just open it up to edit/view the script.